# pattern matching of list of empty list

Tags: sml, ml

I am doing homework for university and am facing a strange problem with the webassign portal (you put your code in and that one checks if everything is alright).

We need to write a function to multiply matrices. This is done step by step using vector multiplication, matrix mult vector, matrix mult matrix.

My code is running on smlnj interpreter, but not in webassign:

```
fun v_v_mult [] _  = 0.0
  | v_v_mult _  [] = 0.0
  | v_v_mult (r::rs) (c::cs) = r*c + v_v_mult rs cs

fun m_v_mult [] _  = []
  | m_v_mult _  [] = []
  | m_v_mult (rv::rvs) cs = v_v_mult rv cs :: m_v_mult rvs cs
```

So, everything is fine in my REPL, but webassign tells me that

```
m_v_mult [[]] []
```

raises an exception. I can't reproduce the exception in my REPL, as the above code works as expected.

Does pattern matching a list of an empty list need anything special? I searched stackoverflow, but found no hint. Can you give me a hint (or link or key word for better searching)?

Thanks,
Jochen

Comment: That *should* match the second pattern in `m_v_mult`. What kind of exception does it raise?

Comment: That exactly is my problem: I only know that an exception is raised, but don't get any details about the exception (webassign is only a submitting portal and uses some tools in the background. there doesn't seem to be a direct connection to a REPL. it's also been used for other languages...)

Comment: I suspect something fishy about the webassign configuration. I think that the best person to help you is the person responsible for the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, guys, the answer is somewhat strange.

```
fun m_v_mult [] _  = []
  | m_v_mult (rv::rvs) cs = v_v_mult rv cs :: m_v_mult rvs cs
```

which is, second line deleted.

That's because, m_v_mult [[]] [] has no empty matrix in the first argument, but a matrix with one row, which is empty. So the result should be a vector with one element, that includes the sum over 0 numbers. So the result should be the identity of the addition, which is 0. And you get this result by the last case, which calls v_v_mult, which returns 0 for that case.

I wouldn't have come to this solution without a hint of the teacher.

Thanks for helping think about that problem and telling me I am at least right in the way I coded it.